# Forge Model Derivative API stuck at processing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Today I have uploaded several models into model derivative API. But the models are relatively small (500KB ~ 10 MB). But the get status API keep getting 0% complete by using the urn after almost 6 hours. May I know is there any issue happened for this API or the issue is related to my account?

My account is forge@airsquire.ai

App client ID is JLtyvDDmgWjDYomj1BXyRB7zTcezF9Xn

Comment: what the file format?

Comment: It is in IFC 2x3 format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a temporary delay in processing which is now fixed.

Comment: Any real-time monitoring page I can check for this kind of system delaying